# material-carousel not rendering inside material-grid

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using @ngbmodule/material-carousel to create carousel slide in my angular v10 app. Carousel is  rendering when I try to render in a simple div. However its not rendering in material-grid. I tried to debug a lot, but I am unable to find the fix. What wrong am I doing? Is there a better way to create carousel in angular app with material?

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="200px">
  <mat-grid-tile> <h1> COL ONE </h1></mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-carousel
    timings="250ms ease-in"
    [autoplay]="true"
    interval="5000"
    color="accent"
    maxWidth="auto"
    proportion="25"
    slides="5"
    [loop]="true"
    [hideArrows]="false"
    [hideIndicators]="false"
    [useKeyboard]="true"
    [useMouseWheel]="false"
    orientation="ltr"
    >
      <mat-carousel-slide
          #matCarouselSlide
          *ngFor="let slide of slides; let i = index"
          [image]="slide.img"
          overlayColor="#00000040"
          [hideOverlay]="false"
        >
      </mat-carousel-slide>
    </mat-carousel>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile><h3> COL THREE </h3></mat-grid-tile>

</mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the mat-carousel selector to 100%... I had the same issue